# OpenSource Driver with ATI HD 6770

Tags: 11.04, drivers, compiz, video, ati

Im currently using fglrx from AMD and wanna try other driver to see if I can get better performance with compiz (I'm getting flickering). Everything I've tried dont works(Radeon, RadeonHD), I think that 6770 is too new; But wait! 6770 is almost identical to 5770! Any idea? I have ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Go to CCSM (compiz Configuration Settings Manager) then go to the OpenGL plug in and then uncheck Sync to Vblank.

Then go back and on the Composite plug in uncheck Detect Refresh Rate

Comment: @UriHerrera you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to CCSM (compiz Configuration Settings Manager) then go to the OpenGL plug in and then uncheck Sync to Vblank. Then go back and on the Composite plug in uncheck Detect Refresh Rate

Answer (score -1):

It is unlikely you will get better performance with the open-source driver. Fglrx is much more efficient, so it will result in smoother graphics, more FPS in games etc. There are some exceptions, though, the open-source driver supports KMS while fglrx not, so with fglrx you will not get a pretty ubuntu logo while booting-up your system.

Comment: That just isn't true. I'm using a HD5850 and the open driver is _much_ more stable and much faster.

Answer (score -1):

The open driver has improved significantly over a very short time. If you want to get a feel of how it's progressing, then you might want to fire up Oneiric Alpha 3 and run it live. My experience is that the driver in Oneiric is much better than the one in Natty. Other issues with Oneiric forced me back to Natty, but the improvements in graphics alone makes me want to upgrade as early as I can.

Comment: jo-erlend - if you also want to test newer drivers on Natty, you could always try the x-swat ppa - or the bleeding edge x-edgers ppa.

Comment: The open source drivers in Oneric does not work for me at the moment at all, the X server won't start properly...

Comment: No, but then Oneiric isn't released yet either. The driver works properly. I'm not guessing. I've tested this. The driver works. X doesn't.

Comment: @jo-erlend: It does not matter whether it's X issue or the driver's. The point it that you won't get ANY graphics at the moment. This may mean that some people will be unable to use the **driver** in Oneric (at the moment).